# Problem with SendGrid mail services: mails are Not delivered because "From field did not contain a valid email address"

Tags: sendgrid

I have problems with SendGrid since few days but I did not change the way I config my web apps (Django).

I can see in Activity feed of my account that emails are received by SendGrid but Not delivered because "From field did not contain a valid email address".

I check to ensure "From field" is valid and it is.

I have also seen that 103 mails are sent today but it is not true. I thought that daily email are not reset every day... and as I have a free account (100 email/day) it could also be a problem...

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your sender identity email is already verified since you are using it already.
Yes, their daily free mail limit is 100. Since you have hit 103 mails the maximum limit in a day, maybe you are account is blocked. Try creating a new sender identity email and check whether it is working or not with the new API KEY. Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

The problems was infact that send_from is no longer accepting string like 'a new sentence'. If I change `send_from = 'a new sentence'` to `send_from = 'noreply@mydomain.com'` it works. I don't understand why...